# Map computed field with vuex-map-fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a question about mapping computed fields using `vuex-map-fields`.

I have a Vuex Store:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  countryCode: null,
  phoneNumber: null,
  phone: null
})
```

The form has two input fields: `countryCode` and `phoneNumber`. I want the `phone` value will be updated based on `countryCode` and `phoneNumber`.

How do I solve the problem with `vuex-map-fields`?

Comment: @tony19: Thank you very much for making my question more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the [`vuex-map-fields` README](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields), edit your store setup to use `getField` getter and `updateField` mutation from `vuex-map-fields`:

```js
// store.js
import { getField, updateField } from 'vuex-map-fields'

export default new Vuex.Store({
  //...
  state: {
    countryCode: '',
    phoneNumber: '',
  },
  getters: {
    getField,
  },
  mutations: {
    updateField,
  },
})
```

...and then your component would use `mapFields` from `vuex-map-fields`:

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="countryCode">
    <input v-model="phoneNumber">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    ...mapFields([
      'countryCode',
      'phoneNumber',
    ]),
  },
}
</script>
```

For `phone` to be computed from the other two state variables, you could use a [Vuex `getter`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html) that formats it:

```js
// store.js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  //...
  getters: {
    phone: state => `${state.countryCode}-${state.phoneNumber}`
  },
})
```

...then use [Vuex's `mapGetter`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#the-mapgetters-helper) to display `phone` in your component:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>phone: {{ phone }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  //...
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['phone'])
  }
}
</script>
```

Altogether, your component would look similar to this:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="countryCode" type="number">
    <pre>countryCode: {{ countryCode }}</pre>
    <input v-model="phoneNumber" type="tel">
    <pre>phoneNumber: {{ phoneNumber }}</pre>
    <pre>phone: {{ phone }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapFields(['countryCode', 'phoneNumber']),
    ...mapGetters(['phone'])
  }
}
</script>
```

[image: Edit Using vuex-map-fields]